# Why Android lifecycleScope can be automatically cancelled

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, activity-lifecycle

When reading this [post](https://www.kodeco.com/9217202-coroutines-with-lifecycle-and-livedata#toc-anchor-002) about lifecycle-aware CoroutineScope, I read the following:

> Every Lifecycle comes with a LifecycleScope, which lets you launch
> coroutines that are automatically cancelled once the Lifecycle reaches
> the DESTROYED state.

I was reading the source code in `lifecycle-runtime-ktx.aar`, and was trying to figure out how come the lifecycleScope (accessed within a Fragment or an Activity) can be cancelled when it gets DESTROYED.

Can anyone please point me out why lifecycleScope can be automatically cancelled? And where is the source code about this part. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`Activity` & `Fragment` internally use the `LifecycleCoroutineScope` which is then hooked to the `Lifecycle` of the component via `lifecycle.addObserver`.

If you check the `LifecycleCoroutineScopeImpl`,
you'll see this:

```kotlin
if (lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED) {
    coroutineContext.cancel()
}
```

and

```kotlin
if (lifecycle.currentState <= Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED) {
    lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
    coroutineContext.cancel()
}
```

In short,
An observer is added to the component & if the `lifecycle.currentState` falls below `Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED` then the running coroutines are cancelled automatically.

Comment: thanks for replying! Voted up! But the question is not solved. I had also checked the source in `LifecycleCoroutineScopeImpl`, the two snippets you pointed out is cancelling a CoroutineContext, rather than the scope itself. If you look back a bit you will notice the `val newScope = LifecycleCoroutineScopeImpl(
                this,
                SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main.immediate
            )` which is in the `Lifecycle.coroutineScope` extension func, so in short, the coroutineContext.cancel() cancels the coroutine context, but not the scope. Can u pls help?

Comment: When you call `cancel` on a `CoroutineContext` that is made up of `SupervisorJob()`, the child coroutines that were started with this context will be cancelled and will not complete which is happening when the component hits `DESTROYED` state. The `LifecycleCoroutineScopeImpl` (overriding `coroutineContext` & the `lifecycle` vals) extends `LifecycleCoroutineScope` which implements a `CoroutineScope`.